# get entity class in custom validator

Tags: validation, symfony

I would like to know if it is possible to get the class of the entity that is validated in the custom validator.

Here is the custom validator :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class UniqueKey extends Constraint {
  public $message = 'The string "%string%" is not good';

  public function validatedBy() {
    return get_class($this).'Validator';
  }
}

class UniqueKeyValidator extends ConstraintValidator {
  public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
    // I would like to get the class of the entity validated. Can I?
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make it a [*Class Constraint Validator*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mlwacosmos

Your validator has access to the root object which is being validated.
Then, the following will let you have access to the root object:

```
class UniqueKeyValidator extends ConstraintValidator {
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
        // This will return the root object
        $object = $this->context->getRoot();
    }
}
```

If this is through a form, the root object will be the form and your entity will be available in the form data `$object->getData();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok... I am going to try.. is it possible to get the doctrine service to access a repository ?

Comment: It looks like there is a way to configure your validator as a service:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies

Comment: though the validator is a service, it is not called as a service when I add the annotaiton in my entity

Comment: @mlwacosmos Sorry for the belated answer. I've justed tested on my app and it worked well. Could you please post some important parts (validator declaration in services.yml, YourEntity.php) of your code so I can see if something is wrong. Thx

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. If you want to manipulate the entity in your Constraint, you have to create a Class constraint and bind it to your entity.